# Dust reduction and removal?

Tags: hvac, cleaning, air-conditioning

I have a room with west facing windows (I dont think the direction bears any importance to this question), but for some reason this room seems to accumulate dust on surfaces a lot faster than other rooms in the house. We try and spring clean the house every year, but within about 6 months, the surfaces (my desk, computer monitors/keyboard, wardrobe, en-suite bathroom worktop, wardrobe shelves, drawer surface and pretty much every other surface on that side of the house) seems to accumulate a large amount of dust. After just a few weeks, you can see the dust build up on some surfaces and write on the surfaces with your fingers. To keep the place neat requires a wipedown with a wet wipe, every weekend at the very least.

This is the kind of grey fabric texture dust that seems to spread with time in homes and offices (not sand dust or atmospheric dust - that you would find in building sites or while plastering a wall). This one room in particular seems to be more susceptible to dust than all the others in the house. Even though we have our doors and windows open an equal amount in other places. The whole house is carpeted - the fibres of which, I believe is a major source of the dust.

We do have a working fan in the en-suite bathroom, which reduces steam buildup after a hot shower, but I do not think this is a source of the dust. But perhaps helps to blow the dust around a bit.

In any case, what are some of the better solutions for reducing/removing dust from the air, and thus stopping it from settling on surfaces.

Comment: Solution: clean more often. Seriously, you can't avoid dust. Most of it is dead skin cells.  A better air filter might help but I don't think there's such thing as a dust-free house.  Opening windows usually increases dust indoors since you're just allowing dust from outside to get in.

Comment: The question was to find a solution to 'reduce' dust not eliminate it completely. Is there some kind of air filter or ventilation system that reduces dust? Surely if they can build dust masks for construction workers to wear, there must be some ventilation system for a house which would let air in, but trap dust particles?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a furnace or central air or something similar? If so, I suggest adding filters to the system/getting better filters.

There are stand-alone filters that remove dust from the air; a cheaper way would be a box fan, furnace filter, and duct tape.

Answer (score 0):

A device like this [air purifier](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004VGIGVY) can reduce the amount of dust that accumulates in a room, at least according to its product sheet and many of the customer reviews. It would seem it can't completely eliminate dust, only reduce it (or perhaps more accurately, relocate it).

[Air Purifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_purifier) on Wikipedia also talks about different types of purifiers and their methods in capturing dust.